# Visual Studio's CMake with vcpkg: Error gdal is not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, vcpkg

I have been trying to build a cmake c++ project. More specifically I am trying to use the gdal library in this project. In the CMakeLists.txt it says `find_library(GDAL gdal)` after doing some research i found, that visual studio can open cmake files by default as mention in this thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019.

Moreover, visual studio should also automatically include the gdal library once i have set it up with `vcpkg` correctly. I've already downloaded the x64-windows version of the library (`vcpkg install gdal:x64-windows`) in order to build for the right architecture and made it available via `vcpkg integrate install` on a user-wide scope.

After some trial and error, everything works fine now, the toolchain gets included accordingly and the library is found automatically, resulting in a configuration like that:

[image: mycmakeconfig]

However, when trying to include the header files (or anything else; see code snippet), visual studio does not seem to link the library correctly as it will result in the error message: `cannot open source file "gdal/gdal.h".`

```cpp
#include <gdal/ogrsf_frmts.h>
#include <gdal/gdal.h>
#include <gdal>
```

Where should I further investigate?

Comment: I think you problem is how you used the CMake toolchain file. `vcpkg integrate install` does not help CMake based projects.

Comment: @drescherjm 
I do think so, from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019:

> Run vcpkg integrate install to configure Visual Studio to locate all vcpkg header files and binaries on a per-user basis. There's no need for manual editing of VC++ Directories paths. If you have multiple clones, the clone you run this command from becomes the new default location.

> Now you can #include headers simply by typing the folder/header, and autocomplete assists you. No additional steps are required for linking to libs or adding project references.

Comment: Can we see your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: I have used `vcpkg` for several projects at work. I don't use `vcpkg integrate install` at all because my projects are `CMake` based and CMake handles the include paths.

Comment: Edit: Picture instead of plain text ...

https://imgur.com/a/CZudsGv

Answer (score 0):

As others have said `vcpkg integrate install` and `vcpkg.cmake` don't work together the reason being:

```
set_target_properties(${name} PROPERTIES VS_USER_PROPS do_not_import_user.props)
set_target_properties(${name} PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_VcpkgEnabled false)
```

this deactivates the integration. The reason to deactivate the integration is so that you don't write an incomplete CMakeLists.txt (e.g. missing the include directory or not linking all required libraries).

As such replace `find_library(GDAL gdal)` with `find_package(GDAL REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries` against the target `GDAL::GDAL` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindGDAL.html)